# Importing relationships result in error message "Mixing specified and unspecified group belongings in a single import isn't supported

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import ~10 million rows to my neo4j database. I'm able to import the nodes with the labels and it takes less than 5 seconds. However, when I'm trying to import the relationships it's failing.

Users.csv header

```
id,"first_name","last_name","email","phone1","phone2","password",is_locked,"created_at","updated_at"
```

Roles.csv header

```
"id","tenure_start","tenure_end"
```

user_roles.csv header

```
:START_ID(User),:END_ID(Role)
```

This is the command I'm using to import:

```
bin/neo4j-import --into data/databases/graph.db --multiline-fields=true \
--nodes:User import/users.csv \
--nodes:Role import/roles.csv \
--relationships:HAS_ROLE import/user_roles.csv
```

Comment: Take a look in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947284/error-mixing-specified-and-unspecified-group-belongings-in-a-single-import-isn).

Comment: Indeed ... you seem to be missing an :ID entry in the users and roles files.

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno and Tom pointed out. The structure must be

users.csv

```
id:ID(User-ID),"first_name","last_name","email","phone1","phone2","password",is_locked,"created_at","updated_at"
```

roles.csv

```
id:ID(Role-ID),"tenure_start","tenure_end"
```

user_roles.csv

```
:START_ID(User-ID),:END_ID(Role-ID)
```